# Efficiency of fopen, fclose

Tags: c, performance, for-loop, io, fopen

If iteratively writing to a file in a nested for loop, is there any difference in efficiency to open the file before the loop and close it after, rather than open and close within? See the following:

```
int main(){
    FILE *file1;
    char filename;
    int i, j, N, M;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        file1=fopen(filename, "a");
        for(j=0; j<M; j++){
            fprintf(file1,"%d %d\n", i, j);
        }
        fclose(file1);
    }
return 1;
}
```

or

```
int main(){
    FILE *file1;
    char filename;
    int i, j, N, M;

    file1=fopen(filename, "a");
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<M; j++){
            fprintf(file1, "%d %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }
    fclose(file1);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why not benchmark it and find out for yourself?

Comment: Why anyone would ever go with first code snippet ?

Comment: Well, in the first case, you are doing more work, so it takes longer. Whether or not it makes a difference in real time, you can only find out using a benchmark.

Comment: It's generally more efficient to keep the file open, since buffers and caches can get flushed when you close the file. However if you are worried about losing data in the event of a crash or power failure then you might want to take the more defensive approach of repeatedly opening and closing the file.

Comment: @haccks: it depends on how important the data is and what sort of time span this is running over - for critical data it might be more important to have saved data on the disk than to be "efficient".

Comment: @PaulR wouldn't you let the filesystem or OS handle power failures better? I thought about this as well, but in the event of a crash in `fprintf`, the file is still open either way. And with caching and all, nothing might be written to disk at all, even if the file is closed.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: perhaps - it depends on the actual program of course, as the above example is obviously not a real program - the probability of retaining at least some of your data though is probably higher if you open/close regularly (in much the same way as you might save often when working on a document).

Comment: If you perform `N` operations, can it take longer than performing the same `N` operations plus `K` additional operations???

Comment: @haccks You asked why anyone would go test the first code. I have a problem that I have to write to a file little by little, and my code goes just like the first snippet code, and I want to know if I leave the resource open or I should close it every time. Can you seee my perspective? I think his question is great.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi; I am not sure why would you like to write to a file on a disk in a batch. But if you would have asked me about the DB write then sure writing in a batches for large data chunk is considerable depending on the situation. But for file I?O it is too costly operation to acquire and release the resource too often. See the benchmark in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did a quick benchmark to see if there's a significant difference. The code is slightly different to yours but it still shows the difference in efficiency. Also, I didn't bother to take in account of caching, etc...

You can see for yourself if it's significant.

The test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifdef TEST1
void test(char *filename, int n) {
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        fp = fopen(filename, "a");
        if (fp) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
}
#else
void test(char *filename, int n) {
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "a");
    if (!fp)
        return;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *filename;
    int n;

    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    filename = argv[1];
    n = atoi(argv[2]);

    test(filename, n);

    return 0;
}
```

The compile flags and bench marking commands:

```
gcc -DTEST1 -Wall -O3 -o test1 test.c
gcc -DTEST2 -Wall -O3 -o test2 test.c

time ./test1 test.bin n; rm test.bin # where n is the number of runs
time ./test2 test.bin n; rm test.bin # where n is the number of runs
```

Machine is 2.2GHz Core i7, 8GB of RAM running OS X.

The results:

```
   n   |  test1  |  test2
-------+---------+---------
10     | 0.009s  | 0.006s
100    | 0.036s  | 0.006s
1000   | 0.340s  | 0.007s
10000  | 2.535s  | 0.011s
100000 | 24.509s | 0.041s
```

So in conclusion, is there a difference? Yes.

Is there a significant difference? Yes but only for large(ish) number of iterations.

Does it matter? It depends. How many iterations are you planning to do? Up until around 1000 iterations, the difference isn't likely to be noticeable by the user. Anything thing higher and you'll start to see some significant differences in running time between the two different implementations.

At the end of the day, if you can code for efficiency without too much effort, why deliberately use a less efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

If you're concerned about performance, you probably don't want to do the extra opens and closes. But if you're very concerned about avoiding data loss, then you might *want* to open for append, write, and close in each iteration. For example, if you're adding a debug print module, you probably care less about performance than keeping every bit of output.

Example:

```
void debug_print(char *debug_string)
{
  struct timespec *now;
  int success = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
  /* We ignore errors in the file I/O, because if we can't write to the debug file we have no place to report the problem. */
  FILE *f = fopen("debug.text", "a");
  if (success) {
    fwrite(f, "time %d.%9d: %s\n", now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec, debug_string);
  } else {
    fwrite(f, "time errno=%d: %s\n", errno, debug_string);
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is difference. fopen() and fclose() map onto the open() and close() syscalls, which need an interrupt to trigger a context switch to run kernel-code.

Comment: -1. How a syscall is triggered is entirely architecture-dependent. Using an interrupt is one of the many ways that can be used to launch a system call.

Comment: True. I was implicitly referring to Linux x86. My fault.

Comment: In OS design terms, any such kernel entry is referred to as an 'interrupt', not just hardware interrupts and software interrupts that use the same mechanism. 'interrupt' is overloaded a bit too much, IMHO.  Java etc. have added another overload, and the term is now generating a lot of confusion;(

Comment: By interrupt I meant the int assembly instruction on x86 which triggers a synchronous interrupt.