# what is the point to create a file descriptor and then echo to it

Tags: bash, autoconf

I see in some Linux bash scripts, such as `configure` scripts generated by `autoconf` , sequences like this

```
exec 5>>config.log
```

(...)

```
echo foo >&5
```

(...)

```
echo bar >&5
```

(repeated many times)

It would seem to me, one could just do

```
echo foo >>config.log
```

which is simpler.  So what is the point of doing it with `exec`.  There must be some reason which I don't understand.  What is it?

Comment: Possibly for performance; it doesn't require re-opening the file each time you want to send something to it. It also has other differences in semantics; for instance, if you delete the file half-way through execution of the script, it won't re-create the file and put the second half of the output into it if it is instead holding a file handle open.

Comment: @davmac I think you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Convenience.** If your target log file name changes, you're going to have to search & replace all instances. This is annoying. You can mitigate that somewhat with a variable:

```
$LOGFILE=config.log
echo foo>>$LOGFILE
```

**Performance.** Each of these lines, bash has to expand LOGFILE -- takes time. Then bash has to `fopen` the file -- takes a lot of time. Then bash can `fwrite` to it. Then bash finally `fclose` it. So when you use a string, instead of a file descriptor, bash has to do a bunch of work to stuff data into the file. One off, two off, this isn't a big deal. Doing it hundreds, thousands of times? [It adds up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26251167/2908724).

**Flexibility.** Once you have it assigned to a file descriptor, you can do [interesting things](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18904/50240):

- redirect it somewhere else
- duplicate it somewhere else (like stderr)
- close it permanently
- apply it as part of a filter